# Should we create new instance of lifetime manager every time?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Should a new instance of a LifetimeManager be created every time a type is registered?

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo1, Foo1>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFoo2, Foo2>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFoo3, Foo3>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
...
container.RegisterType<IFoo99, Foo99>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Or should it be reused for all registrations using that LifeTime?

```
var defaultLifetimeManager = new HierarchicalLifetimeManager();

container.RegisterType<IFoo1, Foo1>(defaultLifetimeManager);
container.RegisterType<IFoo2, Foo2>(defaultLifetimeManager);
container.RegisterType<IFoo3, Foo3>(defaultLifetimeManager);
...
container.RegisterType<IFoo99, Foo99>(defaultLifetimeManager);
```

Comment: It depends on what behaviour you need. If one manager should manage all requests then create only one.

Comment: Seems that one instance of lifetime manager should be per one type registration.
[Ladislav Mrnka's blog post](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/)

Comment: @Krab I wished you had copied the information and provided an answer, that link is dead now and I still need the answer.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek why? If you know perhaps you could provide an answer that we could read, so we can understand too. What behaviour are you referring to?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek - Bounty points now for a good answer.

Comment: For the article, you can still find it in the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20171128151109/http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22642976/10380786) probably answers your question. It says if you try to reuse the lifetime manager, you will get an exception saying:

> The lifetime manager is already registered. Lifetime managers cannot
>   be reused, please create a new one.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The lifetime
>   manager is already registered. Lifetime managers cannot be reused,
>   please create a new one.